# How to check if content exists in iframe with external source

Tags: jquery, iframe, external

```
<div class="cont">
    <iframe id="iframe" sandbox="" src="external_website" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

I want to detect with JQuery whether i got content from other website in my iframe or not?

I have tried different things, nothing helped.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't access the contents of an iframe that comes from a different domain.

Comment: You should be able to check if the src is local or external.

Comment: You're sandboxing the iframe, not allowing scripts or anything cross origin at all, so why would you load a cross origin URL into an iframe that is sandboxed that way

Comment: i've changed that - sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts".
i want to know if the site is shown otherwise do not show the iframe.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find("#myContent")


<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    //here you have the control over the body of the iframe document
    var iBody = $("#iView").contents().find("body");

    //here you have the control over any element (#myContent)
    var myContent = iBody.find("#myContent");

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="mifile.html" id="iView" style="width:200px;height:70px;border:dotted 1px red" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep but this doesn't work for other domains. And have to use attribute sandbox.